# Finding the flow line of a vector field that is parametrized using 3rd degree exponents

Tags: vector-fields

I'm trying to find the flow line $\textbf{u}(t)$ of $\textbf{F}(x,y,z)=(2,-3y,z^3)$ that passes through a point $(a,b,c)$ at time $t=0$.

To solve this as I have been taught, I need to solve this system of differential equations:

$$\begin{cases} 
      x'(t) = 2 \\ 
      y'(t) = -3y(t) \\
      z'(t) = {z(t)}^3
   \end{cases}
$$

Solving these, I find:
$$\begin{cases} 
      x(t) = 2t + C \\ 
      y(t) = e^{-3t+K} \\
      (z(t))^2=-\frac{1}{2t+J}
   \end{cases}
$$

How would I deal with the exponent on $z(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the equation is
$z'(t)=z(t)^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{dz}{dt}=z^3 $

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{dz}{z^3}=dt$

$\Rightarrow$ $\int{\frac{dz}{z^3}}=\int{dt}$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{-2z^2}=t+j$

$\Rightarrow$  $z(t)^2=-\frac{1}{2(t+j)}$  or $z(t)^2=-\frac{1}{2t+J}$ 
where $J=2j$.

Now $2t+J<0$ for you to get a sensible answer.

$\Rightarrow -2t-J>0$

$\Rightarrow z(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2t-J}}$

Comment: How can I justify $2t+J<0$?

Comment: $2t+J $ must be negative, otherwise your flow line will not follow a real trajectory in the $R^3$ plane